# R program to locate a pattern in a sequence

Tags: r

I have a doubt in R, I used to str_locate_all(seq,pattern) syntax to locate various patterns in the sequence. Now i want to count each pattern can someone help me on how to count each pattern repetition in a sequence?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example of what you want to accomplish and the desired output.

Comment: for eg: seq="AATTGGCCATGCATGC" pattern="ATGC,CATG" str_locate_all(seq,pattern) the result will be locations 8,11 9,12 12,15 13,16 I could able to do this and get the output, now i want to count the repeats such that the answer will be 2, 2 i.e 2 ATGC and 2 CATG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sapply` to count the number of `rows` from the output of `str_locate_all`

```
s <- "AATTGGCCATGCATGC"
patterN <- c("ATGC", "CATG")

library(stringr)
setNames(sapply(str_locate_all(s, patterN), nrow), patterN)

ATGC CATG 
   2    2
```

Or you can use `str_count`

```
setNames(str_count(s, patterN), patterN)
```